# qsub -hold_jid -afterok loop not starting

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, nohup, portable-batch-system

I am trying to run a series of jobs submitted to the cluster, one after the other, by suplpying the following .sh script:

Annotation_Loop.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

job=`qsub run_IntersectBed_1.sh 0`
for i in {1..3}
do
    job_next=`qsub -hold_jid $job run_IntersectBed_1.sh $i`
    job=$job_next
done
```

The first job (before entering the loop) is executed, but the next ones are never started.

I think the script is well written. I change the mode to an executable and run it as

`nohup ./Annotation_Loop.sh` (I think this is necessary?) ... but the rest is never done.

I tried -W before, using `-W depend=afterok:$job` in place of `-hold_jid $job`

```
#!/bin/bash

    job=`qsub run_IntersectBed_1.sh 0`
    for i in {1..3}
    do
        job_next=`qsub -W depend=afterok:$job run_IntersectBed_1.sh $i`
        job=$job_next
    done
```

But it returned `unknown option -W`.

What could be going wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ouput of qsub has the jobid inside a message text. In my case:

```
$ qsub hello.sh
Your job 8845476 ("hello.sh") has been submitted
```

You should extract the jobid from this message. E.g:

```
$ jobid=$(qsub hello.sh | cut -d' ' -f3)
$ echo $jobid
8845481
```

Maybe your qsub version, has a different message, try it out separatly and then put a cut to get the jobid as a string.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this years later:

I would use an [array job](http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto) for that to avoid writing a shell script. You need something like `run_IntersectBed_1.sh $SGE_TASK_ID` and need to submit  with `qsub -t 1-3 -tc 1 Annotation_Loop.sh`

This creates an array of 3 jobs, numbered 1, 2 and 3, which run one at a time (`-tc 1`). You no longer need to worry about `hold_jid`.

`SGE_TASK_ID` is where the integer id of the current job is held. This is what you pass to your code (equivalent of `i` in your loop).